# Ways of accessing USB endpoints with recent Linux kernels?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, usb, endpoint, endpoints

I am modifying some dated code (from year 2011; see [here](https://github.com/Geremia/licut/blob/master/licut_probe.cpp#L62)) that accesses a USB endpoint in the path:

> /sys/class/usb_endpoint/usbdevBUS.DEVICE_epENDPOINT/device

where "BUS", "DEVICE", and "ENDPOINT" vary.

However, my Linux setup (Slackware 14.2; kernel 4.4.14) doesn't have paths of this form.

Is there another way of accessing USB endpoints with recent Linux kernels?

Comment: I would recommend to look into `libusb-1.0` implementation.

Comment: @AndyShevchenko https://libusb.org/ ?

Comment: No, [libusb.info](http://libusb.info).